# How to set collation for MS SQL Server using Testcontainers

Tags: sql-server, collation, testcontainers, sql-server-collation

Using [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/), how can I set the database collation when starting a docker image for a MS SQL Server database?

Answer (score 0):

On the container, you should just add an environment variable.

```
String dockerImageName = // here the specific imahe + tag
String collation = // a valid collation, e.g. "Latin1_General_CS_AS"
MSSQLServerContainer mssqlServerContainer = new MSSQLServerContainer(dockerImageName);
mssqlServerContainer.addEnv("MSSQL_COLLATION", collation);
```